# INSERT and SELECT query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert 5-star ratings by James Cameron for all movies in the database. Review date must be leaving as NULL.
Here are my tables
[image]

My way is:

```
INSERT INTO rating(stars)
SELECT rating.stars FROM rating
INNER JOIN movie
ON rating.mID = movie.mID
WHERE rating.stars='5'
AND movie.director='James Cameron'
AND rating.ratingDate IS NULL;
```

Why does my query doesn't work as expected? It just returned my empty set.

Comment: Is the column `stars` string ?

Comment: No the column 'stars' is INT.

Comment: how about removing single quotes ? something like `WHERE rating.stars = 5`

Comment: Well, only two rows affected. And these were two '5' in stars column(table rating). Other columns just filled with NULL.

Comment: @MRX you have to insert the proper `mID` too (assuming that `rID` is autoincrement so gets filled automatically). And your current query "duplicates" the 5-star ratings already present in the `rating` table, not creating any new ones!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have considered all proposes and find out this way of resolving my problem

```
INSERT INTO rating(rID, mID, stars, ratingDate)
SELECT 207, movie.mID, 5, NULL 
FROM movie
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviewer 
ON movie.director = reviewer.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

because where rating.stars = 5 rating.ratingdate is not null.

Hence your select part gets no data to insert.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the query is working fine, the query you've written inserts only the 5 stars that the director is "James Cameron" and the rating date for that rate is null, and it seems there are none with those conditions in your provided data,
if you want the reviewing date to be null, you should add it to your insert part
something like this:

```
INSERT INTO rating(stars,ratingDate)
SELECT rating.stars, NULL FROM rating
INNER JOIN movie
ON rating.mID = movie.mID
WHERE rating.stars='5'
AND movie.director='James Cameron'
```